# Неадекватно ведет себя tcp клиент для чата

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tcp

Добрый день. В целях обучения пишу чат на протоколе TCP. В консольной версии все хорошо, чат нормально отправляет сообщения серверу, а сервер рассылает всем клиентам. Но стоит только мне перенести этот же код на WPF - все. Клиент начинает слать серверу пустые запросы. В итоге сервер забивается этим

[image: Пример ошибки сервера]

А в консольном варианте все хорошо
[image: Все хорошо]

Сервер - http://pastebin.com/c2Ru2j30

Консольный рабочий вариант - http://pastebin.com/0707wqKu

Не работающий WPF - http://pastebin.com/CLpRUGKG

Comment: У вас есть возможность выложить код на гитхаб ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder я сейчас переписываю это дело под сокеты. Если и там будет такая беда - выложу обязательно

Comment: @FoggyFinder вы не поверите насколько может быть глупый программист в час ночи :) Смотрите мой код подключения в WPF. Там конструкция try-catch. А у меня еще за каким-то чудом стоит там finally, в котором функция отключения... Голова болит от фейспалма...

Comment: Верю - мне приходилось и до утра некоторые алгоритмы реализовывать ;)

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось банальная невнимательность.
Всего-то надо убрать из кода:

```
    try
    {
        client.Connect(HOST, PORT); //подключение клиента
        stream = client.GetStream(); // получаем поток


        string message = userName;
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        // запускаем новый поток для получения данных
        Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(receiveMessage));
        receiveThread.Start(); //старт потока прослушивания входящих сообщений
        textBoxChat.AppendText("Добро пожаловать, " + userName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBoxChat.AppendText(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        disconnect();
    }
```

Это:

```
    finally
{
    disconnect();
}
```